# Count distinct values based on multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm a MySQL newbie and would much appreciate an expert tip for my inquiry. 
I have the following dataset:

```
date      UnitID CategoryID  Quantity
2015-01-01   4     s           4
2015-01-01   5     s           6
2015-01-01   4     u          10
2015-01-01   5     u          20
2015-01-02   4     s           3
2015-01-02   5     s           1
2015-01-02   4     u           2
2015-01-02   5     u          32
2015-01-02   4     s           5
2015-01-02   4     s           5
```

I would like to sum the values where the `Date`, `UnitID` and `CategoryID` are combined to distinct key (Hope I got my terminology right). 
i.e. the last two rows are not unique as the 6st row already has the same `date` + `UnitID` + `Category`, Therefore the query will not add these records values (10).

The desired output is:

```
date        UnitID  CategoryID  Quantity
2015-01-01  4       s            4
2015-01-01  4       u           10
2015-01-01  5       s            6
2015-01-01  5       u           20
2015-01-02  4       s            3
2015-01-02  4       u            2
2015-01-02  5       s            1
2015-01-02  5       u           32
```

Comment: What you are mentioned in question and your expected output looks way off ? for this `2015-01-02   4     s  ` isn't the qunatity should be `13` and how come `015-01-02  5       u   ` is have `22` and not `32`

Comment: You want this as the query output or you to want to store in the DB that way ?

Comment: @coder of code, You are absolutly right, my mistake. 015-01-02 5 u should be 32. However, I would like the query to ignore the last two rows in the summary because it already appears in the 6th row. Therefore, 015-01-02 4 s should be 3.

Comment: @ Abhishek Mittal - I would like only an output.

Comment: I don't get this, you want some kind of "group by date, UnitID, CategoryID", but which Quantity is asked for? SUM, MIN or something else?

Answer (score -1):

```
    declare @bob as table (
date datetime
,UnitID   varchar(10)
,CategoryID  varchar(10)
,Quantity int
)

insert @bob values('2015-01-01','4','s', 4   )
insert @bob values('2015-01-01','5','s', 6   )
insert @bob values('2015-01-01','4','u',10   )
insert @bob values('2015-01-01','5','u',20   )
insert @bob values('2015-01-02','4','s', 3   )
insert @bob values('2015-01-02','5','s', 1   )
insert @bob values('2015-01-02','4','u', 2   )
insert @bob values('2015-01-02','5','u',32   )
insert @bob values('2015-01-02','4','s', 5   )
insert @bob values('2015-01-02','4','s', 5   )

;with cte
AS
(
select 
        * 
        ,row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY date, UnitID, CategoryID 
                            ORDER BY date DESC) AS intRow
from @bob 

--order by date, unitid, CategoryID
)
select 
        date
        ,UnitID
        ,CategoryID
    from 
         cte
where 
          intRow = 1
```

Comment: Did you looked at the expected output ?

Comment: @amow count(1) has proven to be no more effective than *.  The compiler nows.

Comment: Thanks, But I don't see how this "ignores" the last two rows in the sum due to 6th record.. am I missing something?

Comment: @amow NP.  For years I have used the (1) or often just the Primary Key (most often integer) and it used to work wonders.  Not so any more - hence my interest and researching.

Comment: If your version of MySQL does not support CTE, just use it in a sub query instead.  The rest should be fine.

Comment: CTE is ansi SQL 99 standard and if not implemented already will be.  In a case Asaf is using a version not implemented, an inline view or subquery will easily solve his problem.

Comment: @AsafLahav The "where intRow = 1" will limit to the first "variant" of the key.

Answer (score -1):

Your verbiage says that this

```
2015-01-02  4       s            3
```

should really be

```
2015-01-02  4       s           13
```

If that is the case, then the query is simply

```
SELECT Date, UnitID, CategoryID, SUM(quantity)
FROM tbl
GROUP BY Date, UnitID, CategoryID;
```

"I would like to **sum** the values where ..." disagrees with
 "Therefore the query will **not add** these records values (10)."
The code above will add them.  If you don't what them added, then explain which row's value you want.

Comment: This does not answer the question.  It is not simply a group by.  My initial query was a simple group by (as you have done), but was highlighted to be wrong, i.e. read the question and check your output properly.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I need you to rephrase the question.